# Parallax Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am working on a project that i need to change the background like every 10 seconds to make it work like an "Carousel". But i cant find a working solution so that why i'am asking you guys for help

Here is the code in html and css and it is the javascript i need help with

Html:

```
div class="parallax">
```

Css

```
.parallax { 
background-image: url("../img/1.jpg");
height: 500px; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; }
```

I appreciate your help with anything you can help me with

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:  https://jsfiddle.net/zaedmfLs/

```js
var myIndex = 0;
setInterval(carousel, 2000);

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     console.log("Carousel");
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1} 
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```html
<div class="photobanner" style="max-height:460px">
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" style="height:100%" />
        <img class="myslides" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" style="height:100%" />
    </div>
```